# Selection in a JavaFx TableView with a FilteredList changes to null when filter text changes

Tags: javafx

I encountered a strange behaviour of a JavaFx TableView with a FilteredList concerning the selected item.
Given a TableView  with Person Objects.
As I need to search for Persons in realtime I wrapped the data in a FilteredList. So far so good.

If I select a row prior to searching (filtering), this row should stay selected as long as the selected item matches the filter criteria. Works perfectly.

Now the problem: Altough it is not visible to human eyes, the selection is removed (tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null) before going back to the initially selected item.

The following sample code should demonstrate the problem.

1. Select "John" in the TableView
2. The Console shows that the selection changes from null to a Person
3. Type "J" in the Textfield
4. Only "John" is displayed and the row stays selected
5. Problem: in the console it is visible that two entries appeared. One changing from the previously selected (John) to null and a second from null back to John

Does anyone know why this happens? I think the answer is simple but didn't find the reason so far. This leads to problems in a specific app and I'd like to understand the behaviour in order to "fix" it.

---

```
package com.example;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.transformation.FilteredList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application {

private final ObservableList<Person> personList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
private final FilteredList<Person> filteredList = new FilteredList<>(personList);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    App.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Person> tableView = new TableView<>();
    TableColumn<Person, String> nameColumn = new TableColumn<>("Name");

    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().nameProperty());

    tableView.getColumns().add(nameColumn);
    tableView.setItems(filteredList);

    TextField filterTextField = new TextField();
    filterTextField.setPromptText("Enter filter text");

    filterTextField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        String filterText = newValue.toLowerCase().trim();
        filteredList.setPredicate(person -> person.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterText));
    });

    VBox root = new VBox(10);
    root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
    root.getChildren().addAll(filterTextField, tableView);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 300);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("TableView Filter Example");
    primaryStage.show();

    // Populate the TableView with some data
    personList.addAll(
            new Person("John"),
            new Person("Mary"),
            new Person("Adam"),
            new Person("Emma"));

    tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(oldValue + " vs " + newValue);
    });
}

public static class Person {
    private final SimpleStringProperty name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think this behavior can be expected. When you filter the table, it is redrawn. To me that means the selected value is unset and reset before and after the redrawing. I have not looked at the source code, so this is just a guess.

Comment: *“The row stays selected”* It probably doesn’t. I suspect it becomes unselected, and then becomes selected again, and both these changes happen before the UI is repainted (or at least fast enough for you not to notice). If this matters to the way you are writing your code, then probably the way you are writing your code is wrong. (FWIW there are definitely issues with the way JavaFX observable values propagate changes. This doesn’t seem to be one of them.)

Comment: To make this more concise, why is what you describe as a problem actually a problem?

Comment: actually, I am astonished about 4 (that the selection remains at all) - filteredList fires too coarse-grained notifications such that the selectionModel has no chance to keep itself stable on the previous. There's an open issue.

Comment: @James_D/@kleopatra: You are right. The selection doesn't remain selected. But the selection reappears so quickly, that one can not see it without "debugging" as shown in the code example.

Comment: @James_D: Based on the selection of the TableView, I change data in another TreeTableView. In one row of the TreeTableView I show Icons. And these icons dissapear when I filter the table with a selected row. I know that the "problem" can be resolved by better code but I was wondering if this is a known/intentional behaviour...

Comment: As @kleopatra noted, there is an outstanding issue because the notifications for changes from `FilteredList` are not specific enough. My guess is that the internal code in order to maintain selections when the filter changes is a bit of a hack in order to work around this. Generally, my understanding is that change notifications don't necessarily guarantee to notify for every change if it's known that a series of changes are happening; in such circumstances any list of changes that results in the correct endpoint satisfies the API. That's a bit unsatisfactory, perhaps.

Comment: @kleopatra: You refer to https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8087910 and https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8092288? Can you post this as an answer, then I will mark this as accepted answer ;-)

Comment: as you found my old reports (thanks!), feel free to post and accept a self-answer :)